# trying to understand what "int any = []() { //code body } ();" means

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand what this declaration means. is it a function or a variable declaration? When I try to compile it in c or c++, it doesn't compile. However I found this code as part of a optimized solution to a question I was trying to solve, that is why I'm trying to figure it out.

```
int any = []() {
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(nullptr);
    return 0;
}();
```

Comment: Particularly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15153194/10543689).

Answer (score 6):

It is an immediately invoked [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

`[]` is an empty capture list;

`()` is an empty argument list;

`{...}` is a lambda body, that should return something that is convertible to an `int`, because it needs to be assigned to `any`.

Everything above defines a lambda.

`()` is a (function) call to that lambda with an empty argument list.

Lambda expressions are available since C++11, so maybe your compiler is using an outdated standard.